# Is there a way to create a constraint in a table column to prevent duplicate entries?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to have access constrain duplicate entries in a column.

The reason why is because I have multiple years of salary that can be entered any number of times.

For example,

```
ID Salary Year
22 $20000 2013
22 $15000 2012
22 $20000 2013 <- Causes duplicate entries in my report
23 $20000 2013 <- Need to have 2013 here though
```

I want it so that a user cannot enter 2013 more than once in the column of my COMP table.

**EDIT:** Added ID numbers because I have multiple people in my COMP table. This changes the question.

Answer (score 3):

*"I want it so that a user cannot enter 2013 more than once in the column of my COMP table."*

1. Open `COMP` in Design View.
2. Select the `Year` field.
3. Select the *General* tab from the "Field Propeties" (down below).
4. Choose "Yes (No Duplicates)" from the *Indexed* property dropdown.
5. Save the changes.

If you prefer to do it with code instead ...

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE [COMP]" & vbCrLf & _
    "ADD CONSTRAINT uniq_year UNIQUE ([Year])"
```

Note that statement will not succeed unless the existing `[Year]` values are unique.  Also, both `COMP` and `Year` are [reserved words](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html).  Enclose them in square brackets so the db engine will recognize them as field names and not complain.

If you decide the constraint should be based on 2 fields ...

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE [COMP]" & vbCrLf & _
    "ADD CONSTRAINT uniq_id_year UNIQUE (ID, [Year])"
```

You could also create the same unique index/constraint from table Design View, but that is more difficult for me to describe.  It may be easier for you to execute the DDL statement, then examine the result in Design View.  Just make sure the table is not in Design View when you try to execute the statement.

I created table `COMP` with Long Integer fields, `ID` and `Year`.  Then executed this statement as a new query in the query designer:

```vb
ALTER TABLE [COMP] ADD CONSTRAINT uniq_id_year UNIQUE (ID, [Year])
```

Here is a screen capture of my table in Design View after executing that statement.

[image: unique index in table design view]

I don't understand why the same statement is not working for you.  So open the table in Design View and find the UI methods to create the unique index as displayed in that picture.

Comment: This is a good answer but I figured out I actually do need to have the years for separate ID numbers. I still need no duplicates within the same ID number.

Comment: Where do I execute this DDL statement? In VBA window?

Comment: You could run that code in the Immediate window (Ctrl+g).  Or create a new query in the query designer, switch to SQL View, paste in just the following statement text and execute it from there: `ALTER TABLE COMP ADD CONSTRAINT uniq_id_year UNIQUE (ID, [Year])`

Comment: Nice. Before I run this though is it making ID unique too or no? I need ID not unique but year unique for each ID.

Comment: No.  The combination of ID plus Year must be unique to satisfy that constraint.  But you can store multiple rows with the same ID as long as the Year is different for each of those.  This should be much clearer once you do it.  Make a backup copy of your db file and try it.  :-)

Comment: `COMP` is a reserved.  Enclose it in square brackets as I did for `[Year]` which is also a reserved word.

Comment: Same thing: syntax error in CONSTRAINT CLAUSE. Is the underscore supposed to be included?

Comment: I'm not clear what underscore you're talking about.  What happens when you remove it?

Comment: I tried the query version and it's the same thing "Syntax Error in the CONSTRAINT clause"

Answer (score 0):

You can  [Create a unique index on this field](http://office.microsoft.com/en-za/access-help/create-and-use-an-index-to-improve-performance-HA010210347.aspx)

> If you create a unique index, Access doesn't allow you to enter a new
>   value in the field if that value already exists in the same field in
>   another record. Access automatically creates a unique index for
>   primary keys, but you might also want to prohibit duplicate values in
>   other fields. For example, you can create a unique index on a field
>   that stores serial numbers so that no two products have the same
>   serial number.

Answer (score 0):

Make your Primary Key based on one (or more) columns.  If you need to base it on 2 columns, go into the Design View of the table, highlight the fields you want it based off of, and right click.  Choose "Primary Key" from the popup menu.  It looks, from a previous comment, you need to prevent duplicates to the combination of ID and Year.  So highlight those 2 rows from Design View and make them the Primary Key.  This will prevent you from having 2 records in the table with identical information in ID and Year.

Make sure your report is GROUPED by ID and Year, which will prevent duplicates.